# Connecting to MsSql Db through Zend framework SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, zend-framework, pdo

i have a problem connecting to a db (mssql) from my mac. I have already installed freetds and dblib with homebrew ad they should be working but my `phpinfo()`says this:

```
 '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-readline=/usr/local/readline-6.2' '--with-libedit' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-iconv' '--with-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-mysqlnd'
```

After this, in a lone section:

```
Additional .ini files parsed: /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/pdo_dblib.ini, /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/mssql.ini,
```

And then:

```
 pdo_dblib
 PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib   enabled
 Flavour    freetds 

 mssql
 MSSQL Support  enabled
 Active Persistent Links    0
 Active Links   0
 Library version    FreeTDS
```

I can't understand if the library is effectively enabled as connecting with the following configuration gives me the following error:

```
 resources.db.adapter = pdo_mssql
 resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
 resources.db.params.host = "host"
 resources.db.params.port = "port"
 resources.db.params.username = "un"
 resources.db.params.password = "pw"
 resources.db.params.dbname = "name"
 resources.db.params.pdoType = dblib
 resources.db.params.charset= "utf-8"
```

Error:

```
 SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)
```

From ##zftalk channel on freenode:

```
 thats usually what you get when you use pdo->lastError() when no error has actually happened
```

This is my mssql support in PHPinfo()

```
 MSSQL Support  enabled
 Active Persistent Links    0
 Active Links   0
 Library version    FreeTDS

 Directive  Local Value Master Value
 mssql.allow_persistent On  On
 mssql.batchsize    0   0
 mssql.charset  no value    no value
 mssql.compatability_mode   On  On
 mssql.connect_timeout  5   5
 mssql.datetimeconvert  On  On
 mssql.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
 mssql.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
 mssql.max_procs    Unlimited   Unlimited
 mssql.min_error_severity   10  10
 mssql.min_message_severity 10  10
 mssql.secure_connection    On  On
 mssql.textlimit    Server default  Server default
 mssql.textsize Server default  Server default
 mssql.timeout  60  60
```

Comment: Disabled extensions simply do not show up in phpinfo()'s output and trigger very specific *Call to undefined function / Class not found* PHP error messages. But is the Zend adapter really called `pdo_mssql` rather than `pdo_dblib`?

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php" does not exist or class "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Dblib" was not found in the file...

Comment: How does your FreeTDS configuration lok like?

Comment: PDO throws away all error messages from MSSQL (usually not this extreme though.)  Run a bare script with the environment variable TDSDUMP=/tmp/tds.log and inspect the tds.log file.  A few dozen lines up from the bottom should be the actual error message.

Answer (score 2):

Check your freetds configuration and `resources.db.params.host = "host"` setting

While ago I used this configuration to connect with php 5/ZF 1.x on RHEL - but maybe will help. `host` is address of SQL Server and `[my-server-name]` is just section name in config file.

```
/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf
[my-server-name]
host = 10.0.0.1
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

and then in app.ini I used (host == configuration entry in freetds.conf)

```
db.config.host      = my-server-name
db.config.username  = user
db.config.password  = pass
db.config.dbname    = DBNAME
```

(my app.ini `db.config` entries should correspond to your `resources.db.params`)

Comment: But i have other project in my var/www will they work if i change the configuration inside the freetds files? i though the configuration should be inside php.... I'll try! Thanks.